# How to display the xml content in the browser

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have a variable in my JavaScript and I have retrieved and stored a huge XML content in this variable like

```
var content = ""
```

the content variable will hold huge XML content.

From my same JavaScript file, I am opening a new window using

```
var mywindow = window.open("\test.html")
```

and I am using `document.write` like

```
mywindow.document.write(content)
```

to display the stored XML content in the new window.

I am not using any XSLT or any other style sheet in my JavaScript file.

The content is loaded in the window, however the XML content is not loaded in the browser properly, I can see the exact content when I see the source of the page.

How to display the XML content in the browser directly?

Comment: Is your XML is proper XML format ?

Comment: The xml which i am assigning to the variable is proper xml only. I used the alert and copied the rendered xml and save the xml conten as .xml and opened in the browser, it is opening properly..

Answer (score 0):

document.write() will actually create the tags of your XML data rather than displaying it as raw text.

Something like this should work:

```
var xml = '<hello>world</hello>';
if (document.body.innerText !== undefined) {
    document.body.innerText = xml;
}
else {
    document.body.textContent = xml;
}
```

Comment: The above method now writing/displaying anything in the browser page

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: In this method, the word "world" is displayed in the browser, i want to display the complete string "<hello>world</hello>"

Comment: Are you using this exact code? I have tested it in IE 7, 8 and 9. All of these browsers display the full string, including the XML markup...

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
     xmlhttp.open("GET","yourfile.xml",true);
     xmlhttp.send();
     xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

<script type="text/javascript">

var xhr= window.XMLHttpRequest? new XMLHttpRequest() : new    ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (this.readyState===4 || this.status===200)
        populateTable(this.responseXML);
};
xhr.open('GET', 'yourfile.xml', true);
xhr.send();

function populate(xml) {
    var content= xml;
     myElem.innerHTML += content;   
};

</script>
```

Comment: i dont have the xml file, the xml contnet is dynamically assigned to my variable on the fly

Comment: instead of that XML file call your PHP/java script there